# Set a column as an index

Tags: mysql, date, indexing, upload, datareader

I'm teaching myself how to code - learning by doing.

In one example in a book the data is imported form a csv file and "Date" is set as index.

```
mydata = pd.read_csv('19880101_20161231.csv', index_col='Date')
```

Setting Date as an index is important to be able to plot the data.

Instead of importing the data using a csv file I would like to use web.DataReader

```
data_raw = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2020-01-01', end='2020-12-31')
```

How can I set "Date" as an index when using web.DataReader? I placed index_col='Date' everywhere but had no success.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to learn MySQL, don't depend on DataReader or read_csv or any other thing that simply adds complexity.

After you load the table, you can `ALTER TABLE .. ADD INDEX ..`